Thunderbird: How can I customize the date/time format in the message header?
How can I customize the date/time format in Thunderbird's message header section (see screenshot) ?
I would like the format to be: Thu, 13 Jun 2024 22:34 UTC+1
The answer should work for the current Thunderbird version 115.
I would prefer a solution without addons if possible.

Thank you.

Though you can manually set the time zone in Thunderbird to differ from your locale, that header date-time format, AFAIK, is derived from system settings.
